# Why does not use 'si' in this sentence 'Ŝi pensas, ke ŝi vidas grandajn insektojn.'

Tags: word-usage

```
'Ŝi pensas, ke ŝi vidas grandajn insektojn.'
```

In this sentence, I thought the second 'ŝi' should be 'si' in the context that the first and second 'ŝi' refer to the same woman.

Why was 'ŝi' used here instead of 'si'?

Comment: La du frazoj estas apartaj, ĉiu kun sia propra subjekto. Vi povas eviti tiun ripeton per infinitivo: *Ŝi pensas vidi grandajn insektojn*. [Jen ekzemploj](https://tekstaro.com/?s=64bc0d13732f8) (ignoru tiujn kun *malpli*), kaj pli da informo troveblas en [I-verboj kun aliaj verboj ĉe PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/i-verboj/aliaj_frazroloj/kun_aliaj_verboj.html)

Answer (score 3):

*Si* refers to the subject of the verb phrase it is in. In your example sentence, there are two verb phrases in the one sentence, so there are also two distinct subjects. In this case the two subjects are the same person, but you can not use *si* in the second part because the *ŝi* is the subject of the second verb phrase meaning if it was *si* it would refer to itself and that wouldn’t make any sense.

It is similar to a sentence with *kaj* or *ĉar*:

> Ŝi pensis kaj ŝi vidis.

> Ŝi pensis ĉar ŝi estas inteligenta.

In those two examples there are two verbs so there are two subjects and it wouldn’t make sense to use *si* in the second part.

On the other hand if the second part is only separated by a preposition then in that case there is only one verb and it makes sense to use *si*:

> Ŝi parolis al si mem.